# Dynamic Controller Creation in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have overrode Rails' `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.controller_reference` method to check if a controller exists by checking for the required constants and then creating them based upon a controller with the same name in the `Generic` namespace.

The problem w/ my code is that it is using `begin/rescue`, it won't work w/ deeply namespaced controllers, and it's rather verbose.

Can anyone provide some improvements to this code?

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher

  private

  def controller_reference(controller_param)
    const_name = @controller_class_names[controller_param] ||= "#{controller_param.camelize}Controller"

    obj = Object
    const_name.split('::').each do |cn|
      begin
        obj =  obj.const_get(cn)
      rescue
        if obj == Object
          obj =  obj.const_set(cn, Class.new(ApplicationController))
        else
          puts "Creating #{obj}::#{cn} based on Generic::#{cn}"
          obj =  obj.const_set(cn, Class.new("Generic::#{cn}".constantize))
        end
      end
    end

    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.constantize(const_name)
  end

end
```

Comment: you can use `const_defined?` instead of the begin/rescue, the rest looks just fine... :-)

Comment: I think this code is good, but it's better to catch only `NameError` to avoid suppressing errors not related to this patch.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this should be a comment, my reputation at the moment does not allow me to comment your question

What about exploiting `const_missing`? 
https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_missing

I used it in an app to declare `ActiveRecord` models at runtime. If you are interested in this approach I suggest you to namespace all Dynamic controllers i.e.

```
module Dyn
  def self.const_missing(sym)
    # Declare class Dyn::MyDynamicController
    # without overriding or patching Rails classes
  end
end
```